# Creating and removing tabs in vim

Tags: vim, text-formatting

How can I add and remove tabs in normal mode in vim? Also, how can I add and remove tabs in visual mode (like selecting a code block in a regular editor and hitting tab or shift tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in visual mode:
select some text, usually a line with V and then hit Shift > or Shift < (to untab)

edit: if it's a line you want to indent then you don't have to select a line, just put the cursor on any line and hit the above shortcuts.

Comment: Or try `gq` for autoformatting.

Answer (score 2):

That would be the < and > [commands](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3E).

#### Examples:

```
>>
```

Shift the current line one tab to the right

```
10<<
```

Shift the next ten lines one to the left

```
>'a
```

Shift the lines from the cursor to the mark `a` one to the right

```
>j
```

Shift the current line, and the one below it, one to the right.

Which is, of course, the generic `>{range}`, so very flexible.

Comment: Replacing `>/<`with `=` is often when you format your code.